# Leaflet Routing Machine - How to set line not draggable?

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet

I need to set the routing line "not draggable" using leaftlet-routing-machine.
Can anyone help me?

Edit:

Sorry, I create a route with below code:

```
        var routerMap = new L.Routing.OSRM({
            serviceUrl: "http://192.168.20.26:5000/viaroute",
            timeout: 60000
        });

        if (routeControl != undefined) routeControl.getPlan().setWaypoints([]);

        routeControl = L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: novasCoord,
            router: routerMap,
            routeWhileDragging: true
        });

        routeControl.on("routefound", function (e) {
            routeCoordinates = e.route.coordinates;
        });

        //routeControl.on("routeselected", function (e) {
        //    routeCoordinates = e.route.coordinates;
        //});

        routeControl.addTo(map);
```

But I don't want to enable client to drag the line generated by `L.Routing`...

Comment: We need more information, like code or fiddle ideas to help you

Comment: Sorry, I create a route with above code:

         var routerMap = new L.Routing.OSRM({
             serviceUrl: "http://192.168.20.26:5000/viaroute",
             timeout: 60000
         });

         if (routeControl != undefined)   routeControl.getPlan().setWaypoints([]);

         routeControl = L.Routing.control({
             waypoints: novasCoord,
             router: routerMap,
             routeWhileDragging: true
         });

         routeControl.addTo(map);

Comment: You mean that after L.Routing has generated a line, you don't want the user to click another point to the map and thus regenerate the routing?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [docs](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-plan) for this plug-in, the `L.Routing.Line` has an option to enable/disable (enabled by default) the possibility to add new way points by dragging the line.

The options is called `addWaypoints`.

Just turn it to false, for example you could extend the `L.Routing.Line` to disable by default the possibility to add way points.

```
    L.Routing.Line = L.Routing.Line.extend({
        options: {
            styles: [
                {color: 'black', opacity: 0.15, weight: 9},
                {color: 'white', opacity: 0.8, weight: 6},
                {color: 'red', opacity: 1, weight: 2}
            ],
            missingRouteStyles: [
                {color: 'black', opacity: 0.15, weight: 7},
                {color: 'white', opacity: 0.6, weight: 4},
                {color: 'gray', opacity: 0.8, weight: 2, dashArray: '7,12'}
            ],
            addWaypoints: false,
            extendToWaypoints: true,
            missingRouteTolerance: 10
        },
    });
```

Or do it on the fly when instantiating the `L.Routing.Control` by passing the `lineOptions` property.

```
routeControl = L.Routing.control({
    /* your config */
    lineOptions : {
        addWaypoints: false
    }
});
```

This will fit your needs.

Br.

Comment: If you also want to **disable dragging of waypoints**, use a custom **plan**, e.g. 
`const planOptions = {
      addWaypoints: false,
      draggableWaypoints: false
    };
const plan = L.Routing.Plan(initialWayPoints, planOptions);

L.Routing.control({
  plan,
  //..
});`
http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-plan